# How do I add an hour "column" to a datetime series with only minutes and seconds

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with a column that has minutes and seconds (datetime). The time series goes for several hours so when a new hour starts the minutes and seconds start over at 0. I'd like to add an hour to the date time every time it rolls over. Does anyone have any suggestions on a simple way to do this?

Code to load my data in

```
TempDataFrame = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=TempDataFilePath, header=0, sep=',', skiprows = 7, encoding='latin-1')
TempDataFrame['Date/Time'] =  pandas.to_datetime(TempDataFrame['Date/Time'], format='%M:%S.%f')
```

Example of what my datetime column looks like now.

```
1900-01-01 0:27:58
1900-01-01 0:27:59
1900-01-01 0:28:00
1900-01-01 0:28:01
........
1900-01-01 0:59:57
1900-01-01 0:59:58
1900-01-01 0:59:59
1900-01-01 0:00:00
1900-01-01 0:00:01
1900-01-01 0:00:02
........
1900-01-01 0:59:57
1900-01-01 0:59:58
1900-01-01 0:59:59
1900-01-01 0:00:00
1900-01-01 0:00:01
1900-01-01 0:00:02
etc...
```

Example of what I'd like to end up with

```
1900-01-01 0:27:58
1900-01-01 0:27:59
1900-01-01 0:28:00
1900-01-01 0:28:01
........
1900-01-01 0:59:57
1900-01-01 0:59:58
1900-01-01 0:59:59
1900-01-01 1:00:00
1900-01-01 1:00:01
1900-01-01 1:00:02
........
1900-01-01 1:59:57
1900-01-01 1:59:58
1900-01-01 1:59:59
1900-01-01 2:00:00
1900-01-01 2:00:01
1900-01-01 2:00:02
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then this will work:

```
In [175]:
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex((df['datetime'] < df['datetime'].shift()).cumsum(), 'H')
df

Out[175]:
              datetime
0  1900-01-01 00:27:58
1  1900-01-01 00:27:59
2  1900-01-01 00:28:00
3  1900-01-01 00:28:01
4  1900-01-01 00:59:57
5  1900-01-01 00:59:58
6  1900-01-01 00:59:59
7  1900-01-01 01:00:00
8  1900-01-01 01:00:01
9  1900-01-01 01:00:02
10 1900-01-01 01:59:57
11 1900-01-01 01:59:58
12 1900-01-01 01:59:59
13 1900-01-01 02:00:00
14 1900-01-01 02:00:01
15 1900-01-01 02:00:02
```

So this compares the datetimes with the previous row using `shift` and if so this will return `True` when the times are less than the previous row which occurs because the `hour` component stays as `0`, we call `cumsum()` on this:

```
In [178]:
(df['datetime'] < df['datetime'].shift()).cumsum()

Out[178]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    2
14    2
15    2
Name: datetime, dtype: int32
```

We then use this to generate a `TimedeltaIndex` to add a `Series` of hours to each datetime